# Составление шаблона в Backbone.js

Tags: underscore.js, backbone.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно составить шаблон в Backbone.js, если есть вложенные данные.

Пример данных:

```
var questions = [
    {
        id: 0,
    question: [
        {
            id: 101,
            text: 'Ваша фамилия?',
        },
        {
            id: 102,
            text: 'Ваше имя?',
        },
        {
            id: 103,
            text: 'Ваше отчество?',
        },
        {
            id: 104,
            text: 'Ваш возраст?',
        },
    ]
}
```

];

И html-код для вывода:

```
<div id="qu_0" class="questions"><div>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_0" id="i101" value="101" /><label for="i101">Ваша фамилия?</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_0" id="i102" value="102" /><label for="i102">Ваше имя?</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_0" id="i103" value="103" /><label for="i103">Ваше отчество?</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_0" id="i104" value="104" /><label for="i104">Ваш возраст?</label></p>
    <button type="button" name="next"><b>Ответить</b></button>
</div></div>
```

Понимаю, что должно получится как-то так:

```
<script id="questionTemplate" type="text/template">
<div>
    <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_<%= id %>" id="i<%= q.id %>" value="<%= q.id %>" /><label for="i<%= q.id %>"><%= q.text %></label></p>
    <button type="button" name="next"><b>Ответить</b></button>
</div>
```

</script>

Но не разобрался, как вывести вложенный массив вопросов в шаблон. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался - делается с помощью _.each();

```
<script id="questionTemplate" type="text/template">
<div>
   <% _.each(question, function(q) { %>
      <p><input type="radio" rel="question" name="question_<%= id %>" id="i<%= q.id %>" value="<%= q.id %>" /><label for="i<%= q.id %>"><%= q.text %></label></p>
   <% }); %>
   <button type="button" name="next"><b>Ответить</b></button>
</div>
</script>
```